# Can swagger generate a javascript client with common JS instead of ESM?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, commonjs, swagger-codegen

When I use Swagger-codegen 3.x to send the post request and generate a javascript client,  I noticed that the javascript client it generated works fine with ESM instead of common JS (require('') syntax). That is, if I want to test the endpoint I have to create a test.mjs file instead of test.js file.
The docker image I used is "swaggerapi/swagger-generator-v3:latest".  The endpoint I'm using is "http://localhost:8080/api/generate". I have passed the option useES6 in the body and it does not work.
Here is the body I send the post request. Are there any ways I can create with a common JS?

```
 json: {
            "options": {},
            "spec": parsedRawdata,
            "codegenVersion": "V3",
            "lang": "javascript",
            "type": "CLIENT"
        },
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/octet-stream",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
```

Comment: Just transpile it afterwards?

Comment: I am wondering if that's the issue of Swagger. Trying to add an additional property in json body so that it can convert to CommonJS.